# CloudFlare permanently caches page even though cookies are set

Tags: caching, cookies, cloudflare

I had this problem where CloudFlare wouldn't cache any of my pages because all of my pages returned session cookies. I've fixed this with a own written method, which removes unnecessary cookies from my response header. It's based on the same idea used and described here https://github.com/HaiFangHui/sessionmonster.

Currenlty i'm having this situation which is driving me bananas and i was hoping someone could help me out a little bit with your expertise about this subject.

I'm having this problem that after i login within my site after CloudFlare had it's chance to cache the page in a previous request... It will do that permanently untill the Edge TTL time expires.

Since the official CloudFlare documentation states it will not cache a page if it contains cookies i was hoping that after a succesfull login attempt it will serve a live/personalized version of the page. But so it seems that is not the case.

Does somebody know if this is normal? Of course i'm interested in knowing a way to circumvent this. I'm wondering how other sites solves this problem. My assumption would be i wouldn't be the first one having this issue.

Any advice regarding this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like supplying a "Bypass cache" setting is the solution.

It's only available on a paid plan.

More info: https://blog.cloudflare.com/caching-anonymous-page-views/